# Dynamically create anchor and jump to it

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, anchor

In my little project I got two pages (`Page1.aspx` and `Page2.aspx`).

My project is about cars. `Page1` is a detail view where I am able to see every car in detail. `Page2` is an overview about all cars.

I am am generating a button dynamically on the page. When this button is pressed, I want to redirect to Page2 and highlight the car I just watched on Page1.

Actually I'm storing some information into the session on Page1 when the dynamically added button is pressed, and read it out again on `Page2`. The highlighting of the car works perfectly fine.

The problem is that my list is so long that it fill more than the screen. I want my page to automatically jump to an anchor.

What I tried to do:

Like I said: `Page2` contains a table. The first column is the name of the car.
The table is also created dynamically and while creating the row with the car I car I want to highlight I'm adding an Anchor:

```
anchor = "<a ID=\"jumpMark\"></a>";
```

This anchor is also perfectly added with the correct id at the correct spot.

When my table is generated completely and added to my placeholder `div` I want to scroll down to my anchor. While searching thru the internet I found that way to fix it:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "navigate", "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#jumpMark';}", true);
```

It isn't working.

My question: how can I achieve that my page automatically jumps to that anchor I created?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The anchor should have a 'name' of jumpMark not an ID

Comment: @Diginari Okay tested it but still not working.